# I'm having an issue with getting my decimal format correct

Tags: c

I'm a CS student working on a project to convert a number to a decimal then to a rounded whole number.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        //Problem 1- Output a score
    int score = 34567;
    printf("Score %d\n", score);

        //Problem 2- Output a percentage
    float percent = (float)score / MAX_SCORE;
    printf("Percentage %.2f\n", percent);

        //Problem 3- Output a rounded percentage
    int rPercent = (int)percent;
    printf("Rounded Percentage %d\n", rPercent);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

I get the code to run as is but don't get the result I am looking to achieve. My "score" int is set to 34567, I require the percent to show as a 4 digit float (34.57), and then a rounded percentage (35). The problem I keep running into is that my percent outputs as (.35). Is it a problem in problem 2 of my code?

Comment: Can you add your includes and the definition of `MAX_SCORE` to your example?

Comment: `(int)` doesn't round, it returns the floor.

Comment: You need to multiply a fraction by 100 to convert it to a percentage.

Comment: My MAX_SCORE is set to 100000, per the assignment. @Barmer So, I missed a computation input? okay, so I figured that part out with your helping comment. Returning a rounded percentage in my problem 3 is the only issue I'm having now. It returns as "34".

Comment: `float percent = (float)score / MAX_SCORE * 100;`

Comment: Hey, I appreciate your help, but being demeaning isn't necessary. I made a simple mistake...